# How to access data from another call to my class?

Tags: php, oop, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i try to create object to access data from AgileMultipleSeller class to BlockUserInfo class but i got error like this!

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
>   C:\wamp\www\shop168.com\modules\blockuserinfo\blockuserinfo.php on
>   line 58

So how to fix it? anyone help me please!
this is my code:

```
$object = new AgileMultipleSeller;
$object->context->link->getModuleLink('agilemultipleseller', 'sellersummary', array(), true);
```

Comment: are you sure you are showing us all the code? doesn't look like there is any syntax error there, and by the message you are getting you definitely have a syntax error

Comment: By the looks of that syntax error, it's probably something like a semi-colon missing off the line before.

Comment: okay now i found solution because i not create function to get new object from agilemultipleseller. 

The code should be like this:

`public function getsellerinfor(){
 $object = new AgileMultipleSeller;
 return $object->context->link->getModuleLink('agilemultipleseller', 'sellersummary', array(), true); 
 }`

Comment: @FirstProgramer please post this as an answer